# How to send a single NFT with expiry unlock condition on Shimmer using wallet.rs in python?

Tags: python, shimmer, wallet.rs, nft

I was trying to send a single NFT with an expiry unlock condition using the wallet.rs library for Shimmer.

I have successfully created an account and funded it with the required SMR tokens and minted an NFT and I was able to send NFTs around. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to send the NFT with the expiry unlock condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the original code to send a single NFT using the `send_nft()` method

```
from iota_wallet import IotaWallet

# In this example we will send an nft

wallet = IotaWallet('./alice-database')

account = wallet.get_account('Alice')

# Sync account with the node
response = account.sync()
print(f'Synced: {response}')

wallet.set_stronghold_password("some_hopefully_secure_password")

outputs = [{
    "address": "rms1qpszqzadsym6wpppd6z037dvlejmjuke7s24hm95s9fg9vpua7vluaw60xu",
    "nftId": "0x17f97185f80fa56eab974de6b7bbb80fa812d4e8e37090d166a0a41da129cebc",
}]

transaction = account.send_nft(outputs)

print(f'Sent transaction: {transaction}')
```

*Source: https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet.rs/blob/develop/wallet/bindings/python/examples/6-send-nft.py*

Although, to add an [expiration output unlock condition](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/introduction/explanations/what_is_stardust/unlock_conditions/#expiration), it works differently.

To add an expiration condition, which for this example and in laymen terms means that *the NFT will be sent back to my wallet, if the recipient does not claim it manually*, one has to build the `output` manually.

Here are the examples that show how to [prepare outputs using wallet.rs](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet.rs/blob/develop/wallet/bindings/python/examples/12-prepare_output.py)
What you will need is the expiration time in UnixTime format like e.g. `1681286520`

To calculate that you can use a site like https://unixtime.org/ or from the GNU/Linux command line with `date -d"12 April 2023 10:02 AM" +%s`

and here is the code to prepare the output and send one specific NFTs given it's nftId with an expiration time:

```
from iota_wallet import IotaWallet

# In this example we will mint an nft

wallet = IotaWallet('./alice-database')

account = wallet.get_account('Alice')

# Sync account with the node
response = account.sync()
print(f'Synced: {response}')

wallet.set_stronghold_password("some_hopefully_secure_password")

# The amount is 0, because we are not sending tokens but the amount field has to have a value
output = account.prepare_output(
    {
    "amount": "0",
    "recipientAddress": "rms1qzsvgp676a3xtru3sh9nmdd2qxzkmktxkgvhxcc2n20y50dq6nma72795cc",
    "unlocks":
        {
            "expirationUnixTime": 1681286520,
        },
    "assets":
        {
        "nftId": "0x244df0071cb93037fa376921b5de2083b8aed1814c26d778f1674cfa47ea448c",
        },
    }
)

transaction = account.send_outputs([output])

print(f'Sent transaction: {transaction}')
```